# What is the difference between clean project and delete build directory of Android?

Tags: android

Directly delete the build folder much faster than the clean project, I would like to know what the clean project has done.

Comment: Clean what? Gradle or "Invalidate Cache/Restart" of the whole IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Clean the project does the same operation(delete the bin and obj folders for the respective solution or projects). But it sometimes not delete the complete folders.

So, the recommendation is to rebuild the solution or project which will perform both the clean and build operation simultaneously.